# ar track alvar - kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros Users,
I'm trying to use the ar track alvare package combined with data from kinect. However, I don't understand how I can use the depth camera data, as exposed in the description of the package:
"Identifying and tracking the pose of individual AR tags, optionally integrating kinect depth data (when a kinect is available) for better pose estimates."

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174474/ar-track-alvar---kinect/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create a launch file for your robot configuration. You can use [this example](https://github.com/sniekum/ar_track_alvar/blob/groovy-devel/launch/pr2_indiv.launch)

Adjust the topic names to fit your robot.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0